# How to remove matching quotes when quotes surrounds word that starts with : or # (regex)

Tags: regex, clojure

If this pattern is detected inside a string:

Double quote (# or : character) rest of word, ends in double quote

I'd like to remove the double quotes from the match

Here is an example

`"#sql/inline"`

to

`#sql/inline`

or

`":username"`

to

`:username`

but `"test"` would stay as
`"test"`

Looks like this does what I'm looking for assuming there are no \ characters inside the word

```
(clojure.string/replace example-string #"(\")(#|:)(.*?)(\")" "$2$3")
```

Comment: Something like ```"(:|#).*?"``` would perform the match but no idea how to say just replace the quotes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A regex for that can be

```
\"([#:][^\"]*)\"
```

Replace with `$1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Mgt40/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C%22(%5B%23%3A%5D%5B%5E%5C%22%5D*)%5C%22):

[image]

Closure command:

```
(clojure.string/replace example-string #"\"([#:][^\"]*)\"" "$1")
```

**Regex details**

- `\"` - a double quotation mark
- `([#:][^\"]*)` - Capturing group #1:

  - `[#:]` - a `#` or `:` char
  - `[^\"]*` - 0 or more chars other than double quotation marks
- `\"` - a double quotation mark.

Answer (score 2):

Or if we might have unnecessary spaces in our `"`, this expression would remove those:

```
"\s*([#:].+?)\s*"
```

and our desired data is in this capturing group: `([#:].+?)`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mn0CuU/1)

Our code might look like:

```
(clojure.string/replace example-string #"\"\s*([#:].+?)\s*\"" "$1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this does what I'm looking for assuming there are no `\` characters inside the word

`(clojure.string/replace example-string #"(\")(#|:)(.*?)(\")" "$2$3")`

Comment: If you want to capture the separate parts, you might use 2 capturing groups as `(\")` is not really necessary to capture. Then in the replacement you could use `$1$2`

Answer (score 1):

There are several good regex answers already, but you don't *need* a regex to do this in Clojure:

```
(defn remove-quote-wrapper [s]
  (if (and (or (cs/starts-with? s "\"#")
               (cs/starts-with? s "\":"))
           (cs/ends-with? s "\""))
    (subs s 1 (dec (count s)))
    s))
```

If you're concerned with performance, this approach is ~4x faster than the `clojure.string/replace` with regex.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with the proposed solutions is that they do not recognize correctly the quoted parts in the text.

Let us call the quoted parts starting with `#` or `:` "special" and the rest "non-special".

As an example, in the text `"a"#b"c"`, `"#b"` is recognized as a special part and `"a#bc"` is produced, whereas `"a"` and `"c"` should be recognized as non-special parts and the text should be left unchanged.

Another problem is that the escaping of `"` and `\` inside quoted parts is not handled.

One possible solution that takes account of these issues is the following:

```clj
(defn remove-quotes [s]
  (clojure.string/replace s
    #"\"([#:]?)(?:([^\"\\]+)|\\([\"\\]))*\""
    #(if (empty? (second %)) (first %) (apply str (rest %)))))
```

**EDIT**:

After reading Taylor Wood's answer which treats only a limited case, I decided to add a no-regex solution (which does not handle escaping):

```clj
(defn remove-quotes [s]
  (loop [processed "" remaining s]
    (if-let [i (clojure.string/index-of remaining \u0022)]
      (let [j (clojure.string/index-of remaining \u0022 (inc i))]
        (recur
          (str processed
               (subs remaining 0 i)
               (apply subs remaining
                      (if (#{\# \:} (get remaining (inc i)))
                        [(inc i) j]
                        [i (inc j)])))
          (subs remaining (inc j))))
      (str processed remaining))))
```

`\u0022` is just `\"`. The latter messes up the code's appearance in Stack Overflow.